# 'findPlaceFromQuery' doesn't exist in Javascript Google Maps Api with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-core-mvc

According to the developer guides I should be able to use typescript with the Google Maps and Places API for javascript. I haven't had any problems initializing the map or anything but it seems like the method I am looking for just isn't in the type declaration file that I have installed.

Here's the link to the developer guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query

But I am trying to follow along with the code examples but when I look at the @types/googlemaps/index.d.ts file installed in my project there is no method called 'findPlaceFromQuery' like the documentation suggests.

This is what the PlacesService class looks like:

```
export class PlacesService {
    constructor(attrContainer: HTMLDivElement|Map);
        getDetails(request: PlaceDetailsRequest, callback: (result: PlaceResult, status: PlacesServiceStatus) => void): void;
        nearbySearch(request: PlaceSearchRequest, callback: (results: PlaceResult[], status: PlacesServiceStatus, pagination: PlaceSearchPagination) => void): void;
        radarSearch(request: RadarSearchRequest, callback: (results: PlaceResult[], status: PlacesServiceStatus) => void): void;
        textSearch(request: TextSearchRequest, callback: (results: PlaceResult[], status: PlacesServiceStatus, pagination: PlaceSearchPagination) => void): void;
}
```

PlacesService API reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService

I am using ASP.Net Core MVC project and I have added the script tag and added the @types definitions through LibraryManager.

from my libman.json file:

```
    {
      "provider": "unpkg",
      "library": "@types/googlemaps@3.30.8",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/@types/googlemaps/"
    }
```

Script tag:

```
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initializeMap&libraries=places"></script>
```

Anyone else ever run into this?

Comment: That is an old definition.  `radarSearch` has been deprecated and removed (as of June 30, 2018).  `findPlaceFromQuery` is fairly new.

Comment: Wow thank you I feel dumb for not realizing this, if you want to post as an answer I can mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an old definition. `radarSearch` has been deprecated and removed (as of June 30, 2018). `findPlaceFromQuery` is fairly new.

The [documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript) has references to more up to date definitions

It still has `radarSearch` (old/deprecated), but does include `findPlaceFromQuery` (new)

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/googlemaps/reference/places-service.d.ts

> ```
> class PlacesService {
>    constructor(attrContainer: HTMLDivElement | Map);
>    findPlaceFromQuery(
>        request: FindPlaceFromQueryRequest,
>        callback: (results: PlaceResult[], status: PlacesServiceStatus) => void,
>    ): void;
> ```